# Layout isn't shown appropriately with Thai font

Tags: line-breaking, naming

I tried using a simple book template on TexStudio with Thai font. The result isn't quite good. Please help.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[english,main=thai]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fonts-tlwg}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\author{xxx}
\title{Simple Book Example}
\date{}

\frontmatter
\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{Introduction}

\section{xxx}
\selectlanguage{thai}
เป็นวิชากลศาสตร์แขนงหนึ่งในระดับปริญญาโทที่ศึกษาถึงการเคลื่อนที่แรง และความเค้นที่เกิดขึ้นในของแข็ง ของเหลวและก๊าซรวมไปถึงการเปลี่ยนรูปร่างของวัตถุเหล่านั้นเพื่อให้การวิเคราะห์เป็นไปอย่างสะดวกสมมุติฐานอย่างง่ายที่ว่าวัตถุมีการกระจายตัวของเนื้อวัสดุอย่างสม่ำเสมอ โดยไม่คำนึงถึงช่องว่างระหว่างอะตอมเพื่อให้คำว่า Continuumสามารถนำมาใช้อธิบายพฤติกรรมของวัสดุได้อย่างถูกต้องเริ่มต้นด้วยพื้นฐานความรู้เกี่ยวกับเวคเตอร์และเทนเซอร์ นำไปสู่หลักการของความเค้น stress invariantsและการวัดค่าของความเค้นในแบบต่างๆ ด้วย index notationการศึกษาในเรื่องของการเคลื่อนที่ รวมไปถึง การเปลี่ยนรูปร่าง การเคลื่อนที่ใน

\backmatter
% bibliography, glossary and index would go here.

\end{document}
```

1. I wonder why texts are over the right margin. It has no problem when I used only english. How can I make Thai text correctly display in layout?
2. How to delete or change the word "Chapter 1" above word "Introduction"? What command control that word beyond `\chapter{Introduction}` command?.

Comment: I can't read Thai, but the problem is in TeX not finding sufficient places for breaking the word that starts with “ของเ-” and ends with “-สมอ”.

Answer (score 2):

For line and word breaking, if you are willing to use Xe(La)TeX, you'll
just need to load the correct locale. As per
[this](http://htl10.users.sourceforge.net/Languages/TypesettingThaiWithLaTeX.pdf),
the following can be used

```
\usepackage{fontspec} % To enable non-standard font selections
\setmainfont{Norasi} % A font with Thai glyphs
\XeTeXlinebreaklocale ’th_TH’ % Thai-style word-breakings and line-wrappings
```

For localising section headings, your current Babel settings seem to
work for me, but I don't think Babel works with Xe(La)TeX. So if you switch to polyglossia, everything should work as you expect.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Norasi}
\XeTeXlinebreaklocale ’th_TH’
\usepackage[]{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{thai}
\newfontfamily{\thaifont}{Norasi}
\usepackage{fonts-tlwg}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\author{xxx}
\title{Simple Book Example}
\date{}

\frontmatter
\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{Introduction}

\section{xxx}

เป็นวิชากลศาสตร์แขนงหนึ่งในระดับปริญญาโทที่ศึกษาถึงการเคลื่อนที่แรง
และความเค้นที่เกิดขึ้นในของแข็ง
ของเหลวและก๊าซรวมไปถึงการเปลี่ยนรูปร่างของวัตถุเหล่านั้นเพื่อให้การวิเคราะห์เป็นไปอย่างสะดวกสมมุติฐานอย่างง่ายที่ว่าวัตถุมีการกระจายตัวของเนื้อวัสดุอย่างสม่ำเสมอ
โดยไม่คำนึงถึงช่องว่างระหว่างอะตอมเพื่อให้คำว่า
Continuumสามารถนำมาใช้อธิบายพฤติกรรมของวัสดุได้อย่างถูกต้องเริ่มต้นด้วยพื้นฐานความรู้เกี่ยวกับเวคเตอร์และเทนเซอร์
นำไปสู่หลักการของความเค้น stress invariantsและการวัดค่าของความเค้นในแบบต่างๆ
ด้วย index notationการศึกษาในเรื่องของการเคลื่อนที่ รวมไปถึง การเปลี่ยนรูปร่าง
การเคลื่อนที่ใน

\backmatter
% bibliography, glossary and index would go here.

\end{document}

% Local Variables:
% TeX-engine: xetex
% End:
```

[image]

โชคดี